# syntax error near unexpected token `(' using shell on Google COLAB

Tags: bash, shell, google-colaboratory

I would like to delete all the folders in a directory on GOOGLE COLAB except the specified ones.
My code works on ubuntu shell, but it does not work on colab when i use either of these commands:
! or
%%bash or
%shell

the code is the following:

!rm -r folder/!("folder11"|"folder12"|"folder13")

which means remove everything from folder, except the 3 specified folders.

error:
bash: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('

I want to stress the same command works on local linux shell.
There seems to be a problem with the parenthesis on colab.
Is it a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you `shopt -s extglob` explicitly?

Comment: That pattern uses extended glob syntax, which is not enabled by default in bash (you probably have enabled it in one of your shell init files, which is why it works for you).

Answer (score 0):

(partial) SOLUTION:

I used another code, presented here, to solve my problem:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/299969

yet it would be still useful to know why the code I originally posted does not work on google colab

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).